# Помогите помочь разобраться. При верстке макета почему-то не работает swiper slider?

Tags: css3, html5

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Aclonica&family=Montserrat&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&family=Raleway:wght@600;700&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300&family=ZCOOL+XiaoWei&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>CAFENA</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="slider-box">
           <!-- Slider main container -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <!-- Slides -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          ...
        </div>
        <!-- If we need pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      
        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      
        <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
      
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]